# AES-256 CBC Encryption/Decryption string using OpenSSL in Android

Tags: android, c, encryption, openssl, java-native-interface

I am trying to write an application which is simply encrypt a string and decrypt it using OpenSSL native library through JNI interface. I build libcrypto.so and libssl.so. But i could not make the jni interface for this. Please someone help me to find out specific methods for accomplish this. I am very weak in C and C++.

Comment: I am a beginner in android. If any one can give me an easy example, I will grateful to him.

Comment: hey first go through the NDK samples

Comment: i build and run the ndk sample successfully.

Comment: _"But i can not make the jni interface."_ is not a clear problem description. _Why_ can't you do that? If you have no knowledge whatsoever of how to write JNI code, then you'll just have to learn that first - StackOverflow isn't a tutorial site. If you've got a decent understanding of JNI but ran into some specific problem when you started writing the JNI code, then explain that problem in more detail (by editing your question; not in a comment).

Comment: Also see [Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: You could also just look at an existing open source android project that uses jni and openssl. A quick search shows that [Telegram Android](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) is just such a project.

Comment: @fahad_sust refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35045068/5939769 perfect working solution

Answer (score 3):

Android stopped using OpenSSL with Lollipop and now uses a library called BoringSSL. Sure you can build it and make a jni, but there are easier ways to do what you want to do.

There are Android APIs for doing exactly what you want to do.

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/tag/android-aes-example/

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.de/2013/10/android-example-for-encrypt-and-decrypt.html